# How can I invoke a service method asynchronously by conditions?

Tags: spring, asynchronous

I have a service method.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    public void doSome() {
    }
}
```

I already know I can annotate the method with `@Async`.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Async
    public void doSome() {
    }
}
```

I there any way to make those caller choose to async or not?

Say, with some helpers...

```
public void readSome(AsynContext asyncContext) {
    if (async) {
        asyncContext.call(() -> {
            myService.doSome();
        });
    } else {
        myService.doSome();
    }
}

@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```

Or should I just make two different methods?

```
public void doSome() {
}

@Async
public void doSomeAsync() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found following links right after putting the question.

- [Creating Asynchronous Methods](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Now I know I can do this.

```
public CompletableFuture<Some> doSome() {
    // ...
}
```

And clients can choose to wait or not.